# Add and remove Leaflet labels of a geojson layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

With Leaflet and leaflet.label, how I can add labels of the layer "my_layer" when the zoom of the map is greater than 10? And remove labels when the zoom <=10 ? Thank you !

```
// ADD GEOJSON LAYER
my_layer = L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature        
    }
}).addTo(map);

// ZOOM OPTION
map.on('zoomend', function () {
   if (map.getZoom() > 10 ) {
      // ???      
   }
   if (map.getZoom() <= 10 ) {
      // ???      
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are better solutions, but if there are no other labels I would use display:none on the Leaflet Popup Pane. With jQuery:

```
map.on('zoomend', function () {
   if (map.getZoom() > 10 ) {
      $('.leaflet-popup-pane).show();
   }
   if (map.getZoom() <= 10 ) {
      $('.leaflet-popup-pane).hide();    
   }
});
```